# Owner Data Skew Prevention for smaller orgs

Tags: architecture, largedatavolumes, data-skew

We have a small org with ~50 users in the B2C space.  Their business model includes importing large lists of records (~500 per day) and working on them.

We can minimize lookup skew by not using lookup relationships.  But the Owner field is a standard field that can't be removed and is used by the users.

What's the best approach to avoid an Owner skew?  So far, I've considered:

1. **Deleting** the old data (this route was declined by the business)
2. Batch apex to **reassign old records** to queues (won't work for obj without queues, like Account)
3. **Moving the records** to external database (breaks standard reporting)
4. **Buy more user licenses** annually (IE: "Archive User 2021", etc)
5. Keep the sharing model and roles simple, and **ignore** the data skew

Comment: I think the first think you should work out is if this skew actually exists (i.e. are one or two owners used for a disproportionate amount of records?) and if it's actually a problem (are you getting query selectivity errors due to the skew?)

Comment: The problem hasn't yet occurred.  Assuming all records are proportionally assigned, they'd reach an owner skew in about 3 years.  So it's more of a long-term planning problem, unless their business grows sharply...

Answer (score 3):

The risk of ownership skew has to do with sharing calculations, especially moving users in the role hierarchy. You can read more about it in [Ownership Skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership_data_skew.htm). If this isn't a commonly performed operation, don't worry about it. If you feel this might be a problem, salesforce.com recommends that:

> If you do have a compelling reason for assigning ownership to a small number of users, you can minimize possible performance impacts by not assigning the user(s) to a role.

> If the user(s) must have a role to share data, we recommend that you:
>
> - Place them in a separate role at the top of the hierarchy
> - Not move them out of that top-level role
> - Keep them out of public groups that could be used as the source for sharing rules

So, you can either leave all your users out of roles, which may affect reporting, or leave them in a particular role and avoid moving them between roles, or moving roles to new parent roles. Note that all of this really only affects administrators, as you can't perform mass sharing changes while there are already calculations underway. Normal users won't be harmed by ownership skew in their day-to-day operations.

In other words, option 5 from your list is probably acceptable for a small organization that doesn't have frequent role changes. By the time it becomes a problem, you'll probably be a big enough organization that you could afford option 4 (creating dummy users outside the hierarchy, and move records there).

Keep in mind that you can also activate a user, assign records to them, and then deactivate them to free up the license they used. Records owned by inactive users can't be edited, though, but this may help solve ownership skew in some situations.

Comment: Interesting.  This org has roles and groups assigned, but they are not used for any functional purpose.  So removing them would follow SF's recommended best practices.  And the inactive user thing is an ingenious idea!  Thanks!

Comment: so if i happen to own a lot of records (i.e. i'm an integration user) and  the role of that user isn't going to change, is that ownership skew, or something we need to care about? (sounds like it maybe lookup skew, no)?